# JSTL populate several dropdowns using the same SQL query

Tags: sql, jsp, web-applications, drop-down-menu, jstl

I am creating a webapp using JSTL - desperately trying not to use Java code and scriptlets.

My site is a football site where I enter a fixture and the players names who took part (11-13 names)

I have a **players** table containing all of the players names.

I need to populate a dropdown menu with all of their names and repeat this code 13 times (13 drop down menus with the same list)

I obviously don't want to write 13 bits of code for this.

Very basic Pseudo code elsewhere might look like...

```
String playerDropDown = getPlayersFromDB();

print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
print playerDropDown;
...
...
```

Any advice/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please remove `sql` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time. Create a new JSP page and just write your select and a for loop with all your player names added as options. Then in your main JSP page include this page.

Might look something like this:

players_select.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %
<% 
    List players = Players.getAll();
%>
<select>
<c:forEach var="player" items="<%=players %>">
    <option>${player}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

main.jsp:

```
...
<jsp:include page="../includes/players_select.jsp"/>
...
<jsp:include page="../includes/players_select.jsp"/>
...
<jsp:include page="../includes/players_select.jsp"/>
...
```

This way if you make the change in players_select.jsp it affects all usages.

Comment: Interesting, so Players.getAll() is a simple Java method that returns a List ??

Comment: Yes, a public static method that either returns a List of Strings, which will work in the example provided or if you prefer working with objects and methods returns a List of Player objects. If the latter then <option>${player}</option> becomes <option>${player.name}</option>.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I've already begun making the 'List' changes to my code. I'll post another comment once I've cracked it :)

Comment: I think you still need to import `java.util.List`.

Comment: Thanks to you both for contributing.

Comment: @thonnor It is good practise to include jsp pages for anything that is repeated. If your footer, header scripts, menu etc is the same or you start to see any code repeated, change it into a jsp page and include it. You can pass in parameters to the page you are including if required and you retrieve them the same way you do on your main jsp page. Happy to help.